# mod_rewriteを使ったリダイレクト

Tags: php, apache

### 【やりたいこと】

特定のURLへのアクセスを決まったファイルへリダイレクトする

例：

sunday.local/app/get/1へアクセスがあったとして

sunday.local/dispatch.phpへリダイレクトする。

dispatch.phpの中でapp/get/1を解析して内部の形式で呼び出す（ディスパッチ）ようにしたいのですがリダイレクトが想定した動作をしません。

### 【環境】

- OS：Ubuntu14.04
- Apache:2.4.7

### 【手順】

1. VirtualHostの設定
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/sunday.local.confを作成

**AllowOverride All**で.htaccessの利用を許可しています。

```
    <VirsualHost *:80>
    ServerName sunday.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@virtual.host
    DocumentRoot /home/oono/bear/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/virtual.host.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/virtual.host.access.log combined
    LogLevel warn
    <Directory "/home/oono/bear/public">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

2. VirtualHostの有効化

有効にするために以下のコマンドを実行

```
    $ sudo a2ensite sunday.local
    $ sudo service apache2 reload
```

3. /etc/hostsに追記

以下を追記しました。

```
    127.0.1.1   sunday.local
```

/home/oono/bear/public/test.htmlを配置

ブラウザからhttp://sunday.local/test.htmlにアクセスして表示されることを確認

4. mod_rewriteを有効化

Apacehのモジュールrewriteを有効にする

```
    $ sudo a2enmod rewrite
    $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

5. .htaccessを作成

sunday.localのドキュメントルート「/home/oono/bear/public」に.htaccessを作成
http://weblabo.oscasierra.net/apache-rewrite-1/を参考に

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.google.co.jp [R=302,L]
```

6. ブラウザからアクセス

まずはテストなので分かりやすく「sunday.local/」にアクセスしたら「www.google.co.jp」にリダイレクトされることを期待してるのですが、403 Forbiddenの画面になります。

何か設定が不足、間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: まずはApacheのログを見て状況を確認されるといいと思います。設定ではallow denyの設定とNameVirtualHost の設定があるかが気になります。

Comment: .htaccess ファイル内では .htaccess ファイルが置かれているディレクトリからの相対パスで指定しますので、「RewriteRule ^$ ...」とすべきではないかと。

Comment: @flied onionさん、@heliac2001さん
ありがとうございます。
RewriteRule ^$に変更したところ想定した動作をしました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.htaccessによってrewriteを使用する場合、設置したパスからの相対パスが入力されます。

```
http://sunday.local   =>  ""
http://sunday.local/  =>  ""　　【注：最初の / は含まれません。】
http://sunday.local/test.html  =>  "test.html"
```

そのため、RewriteRuleの正規表現 ^/$ にはマッチせず、想定した動作になりません。
引数なしの場合は ^$ を、引数ありの場合は ^(.*)$ のような記述となります。

たとえば、次のような.htaccessを試してみてください。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.google.co.jp/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.co.jp/#q=$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: @ban4jpさん
回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、/を削除して^$ としたところ想定した動作をしました。
助かりました。

Comment: @tohruohno 本回答で解決した場合には、回答を承認して頂ければと思います。そうするとこの回答が解決策であることが他のユーザにもわかりやすくなりますので。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: @tomuteさん。承認（緑のチェック）を付けました。次回からそのようにします。